# Setting row 0 of a dataframe to be the header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) that looks like:

```
           0                     1                   2                     3   \
0        date  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_price  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pos  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_trade   
1  2017-09-11             2.8303586                 0.0                   0.0   
2  2017-09-12             2.8135189             98570.0               98570.0   
3  2017-09-13             2.7829274             98570.0                   0.0   
4  2017-09-14             2.7928042             98570.0                   0.0   

                    4                            5   
0  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_cost  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pnl_pre_cost   
1                 -0.0                          0.0   
2     -37.439355326355                          0.0   
3                 -0.0          -3015.4041549999965   
4                 -0.0            973.5561759999837
```

and has a `df.column` set:

```
Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5], dtype='int64')
```

How can I amend the dataframe so that column 0 is the header row? So the dataframe would look like:

```
        date  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_price  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pos  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_trade   
0  2017-09-11             2.8303586                 0.0                   0.0   
1  2017-09-12             2.8135189             98570.0               98570.0   
2  2017-09-13             2.7829274             98570.0                   0.0   
3  2017-09-14             2.7928042             98570.0                   0.0   

   BBG.XASX.ABP.S_cost  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pnl_pre_cost   
0                 -0.0                          0.0   
1     -37.439355326355                          0.0   
2                 -0.0          -3015.4041549999965   
3                 -0.0            973.5561759999837
```

and the df.column set wold look like:

```
[date,BBG.XASX.ABP.S_price,BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pos,BBG.XASX.ABP.S_trade,BBG.XASX.ABP.S_cost,BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pnl_pre_cost]
```

The code to create the dataframe (as it stands is below):

```
for subdirname in glob.iglob('C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/tradeopt/'+filename+'//BBG*/tradeopt.is-pnl*.lzma', recursive=True):
            a = pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros((0,27)))#data is 35 columns  
            row = 0
            
            with lzma.open(subdirname, mode='rt') as file:
                print(subdirname)
                for line in file:
                    items = line.split(",")
                    a.loc[row] = items
                    row = row+1
                    #a.columns = a.iloc[0]
            print(a.columns)    
            print(a.head())
```

Comment: How is created input DataFrame?

Comment: Read in from a .lzma file line by line (no distinction made between the header and others rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create list of lists and pass to DataFrame constructor all list without first by `out[1:]` with columns names by `out[0]`:

```
out = []
with lzma.open(subdirname, mode='rt') as file:
    print(subdirname)
    for line in file:
        items = line.split(",")
        out.append(items)

a = pd.DataFrame(out[1:], columns=out[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this but probably should work:

```
with lzma.open(subdirname. mode='rt') as file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', header=0)
```

This approach is based that your file looks like a csv.